# Getting the list of child in firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Check the Image of my firebase database

[image: Check the Image of my firebase database]

Please click first the link to see the image. How can I get the `KjfLmUnPUaWeYDETp04` and `PlamHmUnPUaWeYDETp04` and insert it in the `List<String>` in android. Thank you in advance.

```
  mFirebaseInstance.getReference("users").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mFirebaseInstance.getReference("users").addValueEventListener(new 
ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              for(DataSnapshot dst : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
               //Key stores KjfLmUnPUaWeYDETp04 and PlamHmUnPUaWeYDETp04
                String key = dst.getKey();

              }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you so much. You save my day. I want to vote to your answer but it says. "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: how to accept that. I'm sorry , I'm just a beginner here in stackoverflow